# ksoap in blackberry 8310 (OS 4.5)

Tags: java, blackberry, ksoap

I develop a app with BlackBerry JDE 6, I use ksoap2 library, I tested this in BB Simulator 8520 (OS 5.0) and works fine, BB Simulator 9800 (OS 6.0) works fine too.

But, when I try to test in 8310 (OS 4.5) nothing happends, I not see the application in the list of apps of the simulator device :(

Anybody knows How I can do works the app in BB 8310 (OS 4.5) please

Thanks